# I've declared a global variable and I've passed a value to it inside a func, the code work, but the variable don't store the data if I reuse the func

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, variables

Here is a small piece of the code:

```
const prompt = require("prompt-sync")();


const ricarica = (conto, deposito) => {
    deposito = prompt("Quanti soldi vuole depositare sul suo conto? ");
    
    conto += Number.parseInt(deposito);
    return console.log(`Ora il suo conto ha una disponibilità residua di ${conto}€`);
}

const prelievo = (conto, meno) => {
    meno = prompt("Quanti soldi vuole prelevare dal suo conto? ");
    
    conto -= Number.parseInt(meno);
    return console.log(`Ora il suo conto ha una disponibilità residua di ${conto}€`);
}

const estrattoConto = () => {
    return console.log(`Ora il suo conto ha una disponibilità residua di ${conto}€`);
}

const conto = 0;

var nome = "Tommaso Montanari";

console.log(`\nBuongiorno ${nome} sul suo conto ha una disponibilità di ${conto}€`);
var conferma = prompt("Desidera effettuare una ricarica? (Y/N) ");

if(conferma === 'Y'){
    ricarica(conto);
} else if(conferma === 'N'){
    console.log("Arrivederci!");
} else{
    console.log("Errore di inserimento");
}

do{
    var operazioni = [" ", "ricarica",  "prelievo", "estratto conto"];

    console.log("\nAltre operazioni:");
    for(i = 1; i < 4; i++){
        console.log(`${i}. ${operazioni[i]}`);
    }

    var quest = prompt("Quale delle seguenti operazioni vuoi eseguire? "); 
    switch(quest){
        case '1': 
            ricarica(conto);
            break;
        
        case '2':
            prelievo(conto);
            break;
        
        case '3':
            estrattoConto(conto);
            break;
        
        default:
            console.log("Errore di inserimento"); 
    }

    var conf = prompt("Vuole eseguire un'altra operazione? (Y/N) ");
} while(conf == 'Y')
```

The functions initially work and the variables store the data. But if I reuse the function, the value of the variable is reset to zero.

I've tried to create a new statement (`test`) to replace `conto` and then I used the `conto` variable in this way: `var conto = conto += test`, but it didn't work.

Pls help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: Javascript works on something called "Call by Sharing"